# Decorator for Exception handling in Python

Tags: python

I have a situation when unittest method calls a helper method,
if there is a runtime error on the helper method,I wanted to raise sys.exit()
and exit the process without executing any further test case,As sys.exit() is being handled & silenced
by the unittest I had to to use os._exit()

But I don't want to do this for all exception ,only for specific Exceptions in other case I want to raise the Exception as it is.

I have pasted the dummy code of my approach

Please let me know if this a reasonable approach or is there a better way to do this?

```
class RunTimeError(Exception):
    pass 

class ExeHandlingDecorator:
    def __init__(self,method):
        self._method=method
        self._clean_up=HelperClass.stop
        self._forced_exit=os._exit
        self._exit_code=255
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            return self._method(*args,**kwargs)
        except RunTimeError as error:
            print(error)
            self._clean_up()
            self._forced_exit(self._exit_code)
        except Exception as error:
            raise error

class TestDummy(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """setup test"""

    @ExeHandlingDecorator
    def __helper(self):
        try:
           """Testing Environment created here,
              RunTimeError might be raised by the called methods in this block"""
        finally:
           """Environment clean up done here"""

    def test_1(self):
        data_to_be_asserted=self.__helper()
```

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to do that, because cleanup functions won't be called. What is your use case? Don't you want to use [assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)?

Comment: Note that `RunTimeError` is a builtin exception. Do you really want to redefine it or do you define it to illustrate your example?

Comment: You can consider using the [failfast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.failfast) flag to stop the tests at the first failure.